# Do no flange low profile shower bases present an increased chance of leaking?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, tiling

I'm thinking about buying this [shower base](https://www.wayfair.ca/home-improvement/pdp/duravit-starck-slimline-59-x-30-shower-base-cbwe1012.html?piid=) or similar. [Specs here](https://www.duravit.us/products/all_series/starck_tubsshower_trays.us-en.html?product=1706164).

[image]

It has no flanges so I am wondering if adding my own flanges for tiling is a thing that I want to do. I am handy but I am afraid that if I make a mistake I might get a leak that will cost me later

How reliable is it to install your own flanges? I'm not sure if backer/sealant solutions like the one in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd-Zaod3SP8) would alleviate the risks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the installation instruction for the base you linked (instructions linked right from the link you provided: [instruction pdf](https://www.duravit.us/dimg/6428229.pdf)), you will see on page 6:

> Attach tile flange # 790112 (not included).

> Follow instructions included with the tile flange.

So a simple web search for `Duravit 790112` will lead you to a variety of vendors where you can purchase the flange that is required to be installed with this particular base for tiling.

It would seem that it would be best to follow the manufacturer's recommendation. If you are not comfortable with attaching the flange yourself, hire someone to do the install and get a warranty from them, or choose a shower base with pre-installed flange.

The reason the base does not have a pre-installed flange is so it can be installed in a variety of scenarios with either 2 or 3 tiled walls, glass or shower curtain, etc.

Comment: I think that that part is clear ... my question was referring to how leak safe is the added flange, even for pros. I have seen some youtobe videos where they show the effect that the settling of the floor, the contraction and dilatation and the aging of the materials can have on these types of joins. This is the part that I am unclear on. My gut feeling is telling me that this type of setup is more prone to problems that the regular ones that have the flange built in

Comment: OK, I thought you were going that way with your questions, but that would make it more of a shopping or product recommendation type question, which is off topic. Hence my suggestion regarding warranty if you're really worried about it. Realistically I would think it would be good for at least 10-20 years for sure, probably longer, and in that time frame, most people either sell or remodel again anyway.

Comment: in this particular case for the above product that flange tape is half the cost of the product

Comment: Maybe (pure speculation here) the tape is 1/2 the cost of the product, @MiniMe, because it's really good tape and it's what makes for a lasting seal...

Comment: I just checked multiple sites and the flange was consistently priced at $162.50. The shower base itself is more than $1000. I think your initial premise of flange being half the price of the base seems flawed. Anyway, looking at the flange photos, it looks like it doesn't just glue to the side, but rather slips over the edge of the base and has a built-in slope on the bottom. I would personally not worry about installing this based on how it's designed, I think it should last a long time.